# Why does `[:-\\]` match to `?` ? Ruby Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

https://rubular.com/r/I5qur9Mm1NjWmB

Hello, I am curious about a particular regex which is matching `?` character.

Can you link some documentation or provide explanation of why this is matching?

Full regex:

```
[\ -\/\[-\`\:-\@\{-\~]
```

Shortened down to:

`[:-\\]`

Seems to be designed to match some special characters. I had some trouble Googling and searching SO for documentation on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hyphen between two characters within square brackets specifies a character range. In this case, the range of `:` (ASCII index 58) through `\` (ASCII index 92) includes those two characters, plus `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `@`, `[`, and all capital letters.

Full reference: https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score 2):

The shortened statement matches an ascii range from `;` (58) to `\` (92). `?` is ascii character 63, so it's within that range. Take a look at the ascii table here: https://www.ascii-code.com